# What is not supported in this NHibernate 5 query?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I am updating NHibernate from 4 to 5 for an Asp.Net application, and received one error:

```
'query.ToList()' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233067
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "query ( query ( select_from ( from ( range ( . _0 RolePrivileges ) a ) ) ( select a ) ) ( where ( and ( == ( . a AccessTypeName ) ( : p12 ) ) ( or ( == ( : p13 ) true ) ( == ( . ( . param002 Role ) Id ) ( : p14 ) ) ) ) ) )"
    Source: "NHibernate"
    StackTrace: "   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.GetClassName(IASTNode querySource)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.Process(IASTNode tree)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)\r\n   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)\r\n   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)\r\n   at NHib
ernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)\r\n   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)"
```

above query is an IQueryable< T> with a chain of Where(Expression<Func<T,bool>>) applied.
My question is what exactly is not support in NHibernate 5 in my case? It works fine with NHibernate 4.

The complete query is built within a long function calling chains in which append a lots of Where() to the query, I can identify the failed spot:

```
var predicateReadPrivilege = PredicateBuilder.Create<Resource>(x =>
                x.RType.RolePrivileges.Where(a => a.AccessTypeName == accessLevel).AsQueryable().Where(_ => true).Any());// _predicatePrivilegeOnResourceType).Any());
```

in above code, it is the AsQueryable() making trouble (as you can see, even it is a redundant criteria), if I remove it, it then does not cause the exception.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Don't suppose you code post your code, could you ?

Comment: I  wish I could post the code, but the query and the criteria in Where are built up in a few places in a long function calling chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in NHibernate (https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/2471), and it is confirmed as a bug, the workaround is to move AsQueryable from after Where to the mapped collection, i.e., the new code after workaround is:

```
var predicateReadPrivilege = PredicateBuilder.Create<Resource>(x =>
                x.RType.RolePrivileges.AsQueryable().Where(a => a.AccessTypeName == accessLevel).Where(_predicatePrivilegeOnResourceType).Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of supported linq queries on [NHibernate documentation](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html) in chapter **18.3. Supported methods and members**

For example DateTime operations (AddDays, AddYears, ...) are NOT supported i have to make a custom implementation to make it work.